# How can we deploy information-theoretic private information retrieval in practice?

Tags: pir

I recently came to know that there is a notion called "information-theoretic private information retrieval".

The assumption is that multiple non-colluding servers have same data set and a client wants to retrieve a specific element (or multiple elements) in the data set by taking location(s) or keyword(s) as input without revealing the client's query to the servers.

I have some questions about this type of setting.

1. Who does guarantee that those multiple servers have same data set at a time?
2. Is this setting practically used by some companies?

Comment: Could you add where you read? The important thing is the threat model. For use can, it can be access to memory or getting a row of database table.

Comment: @kelalaka I just watched its tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEYwMPwPxNI